# How to use a logic statement with column names to subtract columns of a data frame?

Tags: dataframe, logical-operators

I have two data frames, one with 21 columns and another with 3 columns. The colnames of the second data frame is a subset of the first. But when using a logic argument like below the second object ("V6") is omitted ([6]FALSE):

```
colnames_df1<-paste("V",seq(1,21,1),sep="")
colnames_df1
```

> [1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13" "V14" "V15" "V16" "V17" "V18" "V19" "V20" "V21"

```
colnames_df2<-paste("V",c(1,6,15),sep="")
colnames_df2
```

> [1] "V1"  "V6"  "V15"

```
colnames_df1==colnames_df2
```

> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE **FALSE** FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

My initial idea was using the following argument:

```
finaldf<-df1[,-which(colnames(df1)==colnames(df2))]
```

Comment: You can edit the question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: @clinomaniac Thanks!